# Как сайт сделанный на django закинуть на github (и как подключить github'ский домен)?

Tags: django, github, django-rest-framework

Я создал сайт на django и мне нужен для него временной хостинг. Вроде как проект загруженный на github предоставляет такую возможность. Может у кого-то есть подробный гайд, как это сделать?

Comment: Никак. На github pages можно выложить статический сайт, но не сайт с полноценным бэкэндом.

Comment: И что тогда делать?

Comment: Использовать что-то другое, какой-то хостинг или vps/vds. Можно попробовать pythonanywhere или heroku